# Chips - Select first chip if press arrow right after last chip

Tags: angular, angular-material

The default behavior of the chips (in Angular 15 or 16) is if the user presses the right or left arrow it is possible to change the chip in focus, from the first to the last. What I want is to change the selected chip to the first one if the selected chip is the last one and press the right arrow. How to achieve this in Angular with MatChipGrid?

```
<mat-chip-grid #list>
    <mat-chip-row *ngFor="let chip of chips">
    </mat-chip-row>
</mat-chip-grid>

@ViewChild('list') list: MatChipList;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
previousChipIndex = null;    

public chipSelection(event) {
        if (this.list && this.list._chips) {
            const chipIndex = this.list._chips.map(chip => chip._hasFocus()).indexOf(true);

            if (event.keyCode === 'ArrowRight' && chipIndex !== -1) {
                if (this.previousChipIndex === chipIndex && chipIndex === this.list._chips.length - 1) {
                    this.list._chips.first.focus();
                    this.previousChipIndex = null
                } else {
                    this.previousChipIndex = chipIndex;
                }

            } else if (event.keyCode === 'ArrowLeft' && chipIndex !== -1) {
                if (this.previousChipIndex === chipIndex && chipIndex === 0) {
                    this.list._chips.last.focus();
                    this.previousChipIndex = null
                } else {
                    this.previousChipIndex = chipIndex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```